# How can I check to see if a java.util.logging.Logger already exists before creating it?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.logging

I am running into a `java.util.logging` deadlock that I suspect is related to the way that I am checking for the existence of a `Logger` before (possibly) creating it.

My question is: **What is the best way to check—in a threadsafe manner—for a `Logger`'s existence before creating it, and to block some other thread's inadvertent creation of that `Logger` in the meantime?**

Background: `java.util.logging.Logger#getLogger(String, String)` will (atomically, in a thread-safe manner) look up a named `Logger` if one exists, and create it if it doesn't.  But in my case, I want to check to see if the `Logger` is there already before setting about doing some complicated `ResourceBundle` locating/reparenting.  Then, after my `ResourceBundle` is set up, and I know it's valid, I want to supply its name to the `Logger#getLogger(String, String)` call.

I need this `ResourceBundle` locating/reparenting to happen only if indeed a `Logger` does not exist.  I need to have this whole thing happen atomically so that some other thread doesn't do a `Logger#getLogger(String, String)` call while I'm in the middle of setting up my `ResourceBundle`—I don't want the other thread to sneak in there and use a *different* `ResourceBundle` name, for example, thus invalidating all my hard work.

The idiom I had was something like this:

```
Logger logger = null;
final LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
assert logManager != null;
synchronized (logManager) {
  // This method call finds the logger, but doesn't create one.
  logger = logManager.getLogger(myLoggerName);
  if (logger == null) {
    // no logger found; time to do expensive ResourceBundle lookup/parenting/etc.
    // ...time passes...
    logger = Logger.getLogger(myLoggerName, myResourceBundleNameIJustCalculated);
  }
}
assert logger != null;
```

This resulted in deadlock.

While my code was locked on the global `LogManager`, another thread innocently executing a totally unrelated `Logger.getLogger(name)` call thereby acquired the lock on the `Logger.class` object (`Logger#getLogger(String, String)` is a `static` and `synchronized` method.)  So this thread has the lock on `Logger.class`...which my thread (as you can see above) needs in order to run *his* `Logger.getLogger(name, resourceBundleName)` call.  Internally, `Logger.getLogger(name)` grabs the lock on the global `LogManager`.  Voila.  Deadlock.

I *think* that the way to prevent this is to follow the time-honored tradition of acquiring all locks in the same order.  From what I can tell, simply surrounding *my* `synchronized` block with *another* `synchronized` block—but this time on `Logger.class`—should do the trick.  Does that seem right?  That is:

```
synchronized (Logger.class) {
  synchronized (globalLogManager) {
    // Hypothesis: this grabs locks in the same order
    // that java.util.logging classes use.  Should prevent
    // deadlocks?
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time and attention!

Comment: Why do you need to synchronize on the `logManager`?

Comment: To prevent some other `Thread`'s call to `LogManager#addLogger(Logger)`.  That was my thought anyway.

Comment: Is `logger` a local variable or a member variable? If it is local, you don't need to check anything. If it is a member, then why not synchronize on `logger` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Do not lock an object that you do not control; this can lead to problems. Alternatively, you could use a different object that *you* control, such as a `Map<String, Logger>`. You can use a normal `java.util.HashMap<String, Logger>` along with a `synchronized` block in the same way you're using the log manager.

```
// import java.util.*;
// import java.util.logging.*;
final static Map<String, Logger> loggers = new HashMap<String, Logger>();

Logger logger;
synchronized(loggers) {
    logger = loggers.get(myLoggerName);
    if (logger == null) {
        // ... your expensive computation ...
        logger = Logger.getLogger(myLoggerName, myResourceBundleName);
        loggers.put(myLoggerName, logger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it the `getLogger` and `addLogger` calls are already synchronized for you, I don't think synchronizing that block is buying you anything.  I would just remove the synchronization.

Comment: Just to clarify: `Logger#getLogger(String, String)` is a `public` and `static` and `synchronized` method.  That means it synchronizes on `Logger.class`.  `LogManager#addLogger(Logger)` is a `public` but non-`static` `synchronized` method.  That means it synchronizes on a particular `LogManager` instance.  The only instance in play is a global `LogManager`.  Would that influence your answer in any way?

Comment: Are you sure?  From the source I'm looking at `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger()` is not synchronized, but it delegates to the `LogManager`'s non-static `getLogger` method, meaning that both calls are thread-safe.  I would be surprised if a Java library claiming to be thread-safe was not.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you—line 272 of Logger.java (in JDK 6) reads `public static synchronized Logger getLogger(String name, String) {`, which indicates that it synchronizes on the `Logger.class` object.  Lines 273 and 274 grab the global `LogManager` and invoke `demandLogger` on it, which, in turn, is synchronized on that particular `LogManager` object.  Maybe we're looking at different JDK versions?

Comment: Closing the loop: indeed in JDK 7 they have removed the `synchronized` keyword from `Logger#getLogger(String)`.